# rails: Active admin filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm using Active admin in my rails app and want to filter a company model based on country, I have a country column in the company table with data type string and I'm using the [`country-select`](https://github.com/jamesds/country-select) gem.
so what I'm actually doing is that

```
filter :country, as: :country
```

but this doesn't work can anyone help me to get a working country filter?

I know that this code `filter :country, as: :string` will work but I want a select list that include all the country instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would go with filter in AA:

```
filter :country, as: :select
```

What this does, is creates a collection for select, where every instance of `Company` class is mapped by attribute called `country`

## EDIT

As per comment, to use country names instead of code, you can go with following:

```
filter :country, as: :select, collection: ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper::COUNTRIES
```

## EDIT #2

To display country name instead of country code in view, you have to do the following:

```
column :country do |g|
  ISO3166::Country[g.country]
end
```

Comment: this is give me a list of numbers, so i have changed to filter :country, as: :select and it is working just one thing is that  I'm getting the code of countries and not the name

Comment: @djrs12 see edited answer per your request.  Please accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: This doesn't work and give me this error undefined local variable or method `countries_list'

Comment: @djrs12 Try this: `filter :country, as: :select, collection:    ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper::COUNTRIES`

Comment: This is working even if it seem not to be the cleanest solution, thank you

Comment: and how can i get the country name instead of code for column   column :country

Comment: Thank you very much for your help can you please recommend some open source project where can i learn from

Comment: I think SO one of the best places to find answers to your questions and learn :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a model named Soundwave, and has a country field, just contain two country: uk and us.
so, I made a collection like this:

```
  filter :country, as: :select, collection: -> {
    Soundwave.group(:country).select(:country).map(&:country)
  }
```